# Is there a Powershell command to Restart the machine and run a script without any user inputs?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

Im running a powershell script which installs sharepoint pre-requisites. after the installation server needs to be **restarted** and another script has to **run**

is there a possible way to **automate** this process in powershell ??

Restart-and-Resume ??

Comment: With PS 3.0 you got workflows that can include reboots. With ps 2.0 I would consider splitting the script up and running the second one as a scheduled task or something. Read http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/a449b284-f2fb-4964-9c3e-76a02e00342f  modify for your script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the 2<sup>nd</sup> script to the [RunOnce key under HKLM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before reboot.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce `
  -Name "SPPreReq" -PropertyType String -Value "powershell -File C:\foo.ps1"
Restart-Computer
```